# Unusually low insert rate on MySQL Slaves

Tags: mysql, performance, replication, percona

I have 4 MySQL nodes replicating like this:

M1 - S1
|
M2 - S2

Only the M1 master is writing, the hardware is similar (the slaves are a bit beefier), they all run Percona 5.7.

The trouble is that when M1 has a lot of inserts in a small time frame, the slaves lag behind. While M1 and M2 ar able to insert at a rate of thousands per second, S2 seems limited ad 120 inserts/s. S1 varies between 70 and 180 but not more.

Here's the slave status on S2 during this time:

```
mysql> show slave status\G;

               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: *******
                  Master_User: *******
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000799
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 677668480
               Relay_Log_File: db2-relay-bin.000101
                Relay_Log_Pos: 568744098
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000799
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 568743885
              Relay_Log_Space: 677668945
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 1118
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 2
                  Master_UUID: 0b400f69-3459-16e6-a835-14feb5d6c592
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

And here's the general mysql config of all the nodes:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

# MyISAM 
key-buffer-size                = 32M

# SAFETY 
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve

# DATA STORAGE 
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING modified 4 slave replication
server-id                      = 3
binlog_do_db                   = ********
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1
binlog_format                  = ROW
relay_log_info_repository=TABLE
relay_log_recovery = ON

# CACHES AND LIMITS 
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 2000
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 2048

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 100M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 90G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 48

# LOGGING 
log-error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Also, checking on the processes on S2 i only get the:

```
Waiting for master to send event
Reading event from the relay log
```

Any help or idea to get to the bottom of this would be highly appreciated.

Update: here's a visual [image]

Update 2: it's not just the inserts, it's everything except selects:
[image]

Comment: Does [slave_parallel_workers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#sysvar_slave_parallel_workers) > 1 help?

Comment: S2 only Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: After much digging and "solving" it with modifying innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit, we suspect the consumer grade SSDs (which are the same exact model on S1 and S2) to be the culprit (limited fsyncs per second). We have consumer grade SSDs on masters too, but different models.

Comment: It would be worth looking at your S2 data requested yesterday - middle of next week.

Comment: Perhaps the topology is `S1 <- M1 <-> M2 -> S2` ?  Is it "dual master"?  Are you writing to both Masters?  What is the ping time between them?

Comment: Why does "Update 2" graph show lots of deletes, yet delete=0.0/sec ?

Comment: We have master to master replication for redundancy. Downtime is not an option. The legend on the right is on a specific time point, i think i was checking a point before the delete when i made the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2 -- This will make lots of one-row inserts run faster, but be less crash-proof.

"Batch" inserts (multiple rows in a single `INSERT`) will run a lot faster.  (Of course, this may or may not be practical.)

Use the Slowlog on the slave to determine whether something else is involved in the sluggishness.  Include

```
long_query_time = 0.2
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
log_slow_slave_statements = ON
```

Use, for example, `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog.

What is the ping time between each pair of nodes in the replication setup?

M1 seems to have a burst of `SELECTs` every 2-3 seconds.  M2 has a similar situation, but every 10 seconds.  What is going on?

Comment: Setting the trx-commit to 2 is what we end up doing. It's not crash safe, but since it's a slave we can rebuild the replica without downtime if something goes wrong. We have slow logs enabled and digested on all nodes, there's nothing on the slaves that takes more than 1 sec. The nodes are in a Gigabit NAT and there is no network issues. At the time of the screenshot the service that usually reads from S2 was moved to M2 because S2 was behind. Different services on M1 and M2 (UI and API respectively).

Comment: @BobbyTables - "Gigabit" is throughput; what is the "latency"?  If the Slave is on the other side of the world, it may be 200ms away.

Comment: @BobbyTables - I still don't understand your topology.  These don't fit together:  "Only the M1 master is writing" and "Different services on M1 and M2".

Comment: The machines are in the same physical switch, so there's no latency. Usually M1 writes all the data and reads it for the UI requests and S2 reads data for the API requests.

Comment: @BobbyTables - all 4 servers have all the data (both UI and API)?  It sounds like there is a lot more UI than API (or vice versa)?  By splitting that way, you have created the imbalance?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: API >> UI, but the node that serves the UI also makes all the writing for the API, so that balances things a little. It's not an even split by any means.